# Getting pure HTML/tags

Tags: php, get, simple-html-dom, guzzle

I have a cronjob, that i want to periodicly check one of my sites for a certain tag/class - using guzzlehttp pools. So far i have the following code:

```
    $oClient             = new Client(['expect' => false]);

    foreach ($aDomains as $iDomainKey => $oDomain) 
    {          
        array_push($aCreatedRequests, new Request('GET', $oDomain));
    }

    $pool = new Pool($oClient, $aCreatedRequests, 
    [
        'concurrency' => 50,
        'options' => ['timeout' => 10],
        'fulfilled'   => function ($response, $index) use (&$aAcceptedResponse) 
        {               
            $json = json_decode((string)$response->getBody()->getContents());
            
        },
        'rejected'    => function ($reason, $index) use(&$aRejectedResponses)  
        {
            $aRejectedResponses[] = $index;
        },
    ]);

    $promise = $pool->promise();
    $promise->wait();
```

this does give me the HTML (but very slow), and it seems like its just going in a loop and also downloading all the shit libs/frameworks i have on my site - and as stated above, i want/need ONLY the HTML, so i can use simple_html_dom to find my tag/class.
I have read some of the guzzle documentation (and that got me to this point) - but i seem to be unable to get further - and my google ninja skills doesnt get me further either.
so i ask here; is their any proper way i can do this?

Answer (score -1):

So after quite alot more time, trying to solve this - i stumbled into something that works

```
$oClient             = new Client(['expect' => false]);
$aAcceptedResponse   = [];
$aRejectedResponses  = []; 
foreach ($aDomains as $iDomainKey => $oDomain) 
{          
    array_push($aCreatedRequests, new Request('GET', $oDomain));
}

$pool = new Pool($oClient, $aCreatedRequests, 
[
    'concurrency' => 50,
    'options' => ['timeout' => 10],
    'fulfilled'   => function ($response, $index) use (&$aAcceptedResponse) 
    {               
        $aAcceptedResponse[$index] = $response->getBody()->getContents();
        // $json = json_decode((string)$response->getBody()->getContents());
        
    },
    'rejected'    => function ($reason, $index) use(&$aRejectedResponses)  
    {
        $aRejectedResponses[] = $index;
    },
]);

$promise = $pool->promise();
$promise->wait();

foreach($aAcceptedResponse as $iTest => $sHTLM)
{
    $simpleHTMLDom = str_get_html($sHTLM);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r(count($simpleHTMLDom->find('.td-icon-star')));
    echo '</pre>';
}
```